# Creating and writing a file with python on an afp volume buggy

Tags: python, linux, raspbian, fuse, afp

Is there a known problem to write on an mounted afp volume with python (2.7.3)?

```
>f = open("/mnt/foo/test.txt","w+");
```

this results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/mnt/foo/test.txt'
```

python creats the file but I'm unable too use the file-object. When I'm trying the same as before but with an existing file, everything works without an error.

Comment: you must give enough permissions on the file to use

Comment: True. Permission to read and write files is not enough. I also execution rights. :|

Comment: I give an answer then to mark this question as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the permissions of `/mnt/foo/test.txt` file. That would resolve the problem.

Comment: Read and write permissions are not sufficient to create and write a file at once. If execution permission are granted everything works.